# Sync between the master and the origin repositories on github

Tags: git, github, repository

I am curious to know whether the remote master repo that has been forked is always in sync with the origin repo. Does it also need updating before it is cloned to a local directory or it is always updated you can just download it?

Comment: Can you maybe provide an example? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: lets say I find a repo on github named `stackoverflow/mainrepo` and I fork it as one of my repos to become `user_name/mainrepo`. The question is, is `user_name/mainrepo` always in sync with `stackoverflow/mainrepo` whenever changes are made to the origin or I need to update my forked repo myself everytime the origin is updated?

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: @EnockKasaadha have you followed the approach given in the answer to sync. You need to update the fork if there are any changes in main repo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to update it after cloning regularly to keep branches even.

You can sync it by these git commands

For example:

- `master` is branch name which you want to keep in `sync`
- remote repo is `upstream`
- origin repo is `origin`

To pull the latest changes and update the master with upstream.

Follow these steps:

1. `git pull upstream master`
2. `git push origin master`

Now your upstream head and master head are same and master is even with upstream.